# Changing the font of an SWT Shell

Tags: java, swt

I'm developing a Java/SWT application. It seems that the method Shell.setFont()  is not working. I have assigned the same font to Labls, Texts, etc, and all of them are displayed properly, but the font of the shell text does not change as expected.

Comment: Which platform/operation system are you using? Please also amend your question with a standalone code snippet to reproduce your setup.

Comment: What text are you trying to set the font for? You can't change the font of the window title which is controlled by the OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least on Windows, the font of the window caption is controlled by the operation system and cannot be changed.

In order to change to font of controls that are contained in the shell, you should assign the font directly to the respective controls.